# How create Java Applications in NetBeans on MacOS?

Tags: java, netbeans

I would like to select the Java Applications category in NetBeans on MacOS when creating the Java project and then on. But I just don't have this option.
I installed a JDK 8u251 before that.
[image: Available options at creation]

Answer (score 0):

First, you to Tools > Plugins > Installed and ensure that Java SE is activated. If not, select it and click the "Activate" button. 
[image: Plugin window]

Then close this window and go to File > New project

Now you can choose Java with Ant, Java with Gradle or Java with Maven project.
[image]